# How to log in to X (Twitter) using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
def tweet_at_provider(self):
    self.driver.get("https://twitter.com/?logout=1703191446777")
    wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30)
    sign_in=wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div[5]/a/div')))
    sign_in.click()
    time.sleep(3)
    email=self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="layers"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[5]/label/div/div[2]/div/input')
    email.send_keys(X_EMAIL)
    email.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30)
    next_button= wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="layers"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[6]/div')))
    next_button.click()
    wait=WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30)
    password=wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="layers"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div/label/div/div[2]/div[1]/input')))
    password.send_keys(X_PASSWORD)
    password.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30)
    log_in=wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="layers"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div')))
    log_in.click()
```

I'm trying to automatize log in to X using Python and Selenium but I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\38161\PycharmProjects\XComplainBot\main.py", line 46, in <module>
    bot.tweet_at_provider()
  File "C:\Users\38161\PycharmProjects\XComplainBot\main.py", line 35, in tweet_at_provider
    next_button= wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="layers"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[6]/div')))
  File "C:\Users\38161\PycharmProjects\XComplainBot\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 105, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF620092142+3514994]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF61FCB0CE2]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF61FB576AA]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF61FBA1860]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF61FBA197C]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF61FBE4EE7]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF61FBC602F]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF61FBE28F6]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF61FBC5D93]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF61FB94BDC]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF61FB95C64]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6200BE16B+3695259]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF620116737+4057191]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF62010E4E3+4023827]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF61FDE04F9+689705]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF61FCBC048]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF61FCB8044]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF61FCB81C9]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF61FCA88C4]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FF896867344+20]
    RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FF896E626B1+33]
```

I tried uping the waiting time to 60 but it still doesn't work.The programm also does click on the next button,but won't enter password.

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: you should check what you have in `driver.page_source` because server may send HTML with different classes or IDs. Other problem can be when item is inside `<iframe>` because it needs `switch_to.frame()`. Other problem can be using log xpath with `div` and `[2]` because browser may not see some elements or they may have different number of elements. Better use classes and IDs or other unique values in item (ie. `data-item`, `name`, inner text `[contains(@text, "Hello")]`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use absolute xpath - it's quite unstable solution, because path to your element can be easily changed by rendering logic.

Each your input / submit has unique locator.

- User name field css selector is `input[autocomplete=username]`
- Next button selector is `[role=button].r-13qz1uu`
- Password button selector is `[type=password]`
- Login button selector is `[data-testid*=Login_Button]`
- To check that user is logged you can, for example, for checking that Direct Message block is rendered by selector `[data-testid=AppTabBar_DirectMessage_Link]`

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://twitter.com/i/flow/login')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

username = wait.until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[autocomplete=username]'))
)
username.send_keys("username")

login_button = wait.until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[role=button].r-13qz1uu'))
)
login_button.click()

password = wait.until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[type=password]'))
)
password.send_keys("password")

login_button = wait.until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[data-testid*=Login_Button]'))
)
login_button.click()

direct_message_link = wait.until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[data-testid=AppTabBar_DirectMessage_Link]'))
)
```